# Is it possible to partial update a RealmObject

Tags: android, realm

My app gets it data from a REST API.
Depending on the endpoint I get list of complete or partial `Account`.
When the API responds I call `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(accounts)`.

My problem is that if a complete `account` is already stored in realm and the same partial `account` but where `relation_tx`, `relation_rx`, `message_last_rx`, `message_last_tx` are `null` is in the `accounts` list, the complete `account` is overriden completely.

I only want realm to update fields which are not `null`.
Any suggestions?

Any way I can override the `Account.update()` method?

```
@RealmClass
public class Account extends RealmObject {

    public String timestamp;

    @PrimaryKey
    public long id;

    public String name;

    public String email;

    public Relation relation_tx;

    public Relation relation_rx;

    public Message message_last_rx;

    public Message message_last_tx;
}
```

Comment: What is a `Relation` and why does it exist?

Comment: `Relation` is just an object that defines the relation to another account

Comment: Personally I recommend the manual `if(x != null) obj.setX(x)` approach, considering that's explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll have to manually compare. Don't call `realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(accounts)` with the content from the server.

Instead, name your server response serverAccounts. For every account in it: get the account (localAccount) with this id from Realm. If not found (null): add the serverAccount to the DB. If found: update your four fields manually on the localAccount and save the localAccount to the DB.

To optimize the above, you might want to do a single Realm query with a list of ids (from the serverAccounts) and save your changes in one batch to Realm as well.

Comment: Hi Frank. I thought about that already but I hope there is another solution.

Comment: Hi. Not that I know of. Let me know if you find one.

Comment: You can use `createOrUpdateAllFromJson()` . All our json methods only update fields actually present.

Comment: (the JSON import method works only if your JSON object is the exact same structure as the Realm schema though, field names included.)

Comment: @ChristianMelchior The thing is that all the fields are present but `null`